# Is it possible to transfer changes from dev to master as new commit?

Tags: git

Currently I have 2 branches (`dev` and `masster`). In `dev` i have a lot of commits. I want to transfer the current version of project from `dev` to `master` except all those commits. Like just copy all files in `dev`, then checkout to `master`, paste it and commit like `New version`. Is it possible?

Comment: We used to use the main branch, with all the commits and then branch out for each release.  Then you have a clean-ish branch and you can make urgent changes if necessary to releases.

Comment: To clarify: You want your `master` branch to have the same state as the `dev` branch, but without the version history that you would get when simply merging the two branches. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

`git merge --squash` sounds like it will do something similar to what you want. Merges all the commits from `dev` onto `master` as a single commit.

Detailed docs can be found on [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).